# How to use mouseX and mouseY to remove a sprite

Tags: javascript, p5.js, p5.play

Using p5.js / p5.play I'm trying to click a moving sprite, but stuck on how to get the moving sprites coords and position. At the moment when I click anywhere on the canvas a random sprite disappears. I've been trying to use mouseX and mouseY. Very new to coding and just trying to learn fundamentals.

```js
let enemy;

let spawnTimer = 0;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(900, 900);
  spritegroup = new Group();
  clickedgroup = new Group();
}

function draw() {
  background(255, 255, 255);

  spritegroup.cull(20);
  clickedgroup.cull(20);
  spawnSprites();
  spriteClicked();
  drawSprites();
}

function spawnSprites() {
  if (spawnTimer === 60) {
    for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
      var angle = random(360);
      var x = random(50, 850);
      var y = -5 * sin(radians(angle));

      createEnemy(3, x, y);
      spawnTimer = 0;
    }
  }

  spawnTimer++;
}

function createEnemy(type, x, y) {
  enemy = createSprite(x, y);
  enemy[floor(random(0, 4))];

  enemy.setSpeed(3.5 - type / 2, 90);
  spritegroup.add(enemy);
  enemy.setCollider("rectangle", 0, 0, 100, 100);
  enemy.debug = true;

  return enemy;
}

function spriteClicked() {
  if (mouseIsPressed == true)
    if (
      (mouseX > enemy.position.x,
      enemy.position.y && mouseY > enemy.position.x,
      enemy.position.y)
    ) {
      enemy.remove();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use `sprite.mouse` :)

https://p5play.org/learn/input_devices.html?page=3

Answer (score 0):

To do what you asked  you would do something like this:

```js
if (enemy.x == mouse.x && enemy.y == mouse.y) {
    if (mouse.presses()) {
    enemy.remove()
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@1/lib/p5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@1/lib/addons/p5.sound.min.js"></script>
        
<script src="https://p5play.org/v3/planck.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://p5play.org/v3/p5play.js"></script>
```

this adds lines but you could do it much simpler.

The way I would do it is something like this.

```js
function spriteClicked() {

if (enemy.mouse.pressing())
  enemy.remove()
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@1/lib/p5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@1/lib/addons/p5.sound.min.js"></script>
        
<script src="https://p5play.org/v3/planck.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://p5play.org/v3/p5play.js"></script>
```

let me know if this helped!

Comment: This is a good solution for removing a sprite, but doesn't answer the OP's question, which is how to use mouseX and mouseY to determine whether the mouse is over a sprite's position. It'd be valuable to answer that first, _then_ explain why your solution is better for getting the desired end result.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're repeatedly changing the value of the global `enemy` variable by calling the `createEnemy()` method from within a loop, which means the sprite that's disappearing is always going to be the last one spawned. One way to address that bit without changing everything else would be to make the `spriteGroup` variable global, then iterate through the `spriteGroup` inside another method and call `spriteClicked()` on each member of the group to see if it's under the mouse's position. Note, however, that won't be a very efficient way of fixing this, as the other answers allude to.